# Como acceder a variables creadas dentro de un foreach de una misma clase clase jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, instancias

Cual seria la mejor forma de poder acceder a la variable  sin tener que guardarlo en un array, ya que se encuentra en un foreach y necesitaría tener acceso a esa variable en la función de handleSeek y como esa variable cambia cada vez que corre una iteración no tengo forma de acceder a ella

```
const handleSeek = (event) =>{
    console.log(event);
    //player <-- necesito acceder a su propia instancia
    
}   

$('.js_player').each(function(i, obj) {
    let video = $(this);
    const player = new Plyr(video,options);
    const cTime = player.currentTime;
    console.log(cTime);
    player.on('seeking', handleSeek);
});
```

Comment: el `event` no te llega con alguna propiedad que haga referencia al player?

Comment: @Pipe si si se puede gracias

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Answer (score 0):

```
const handleSeek = (event) =>{
    console.log(event.detail.plyr); // <---

    
}   

$('.js_player').each(function(i, obj) {
    let video = $(this);
    const player = new Plyr(video,options);
    const cTime = player.currentTime;
    this.player
    console.log(cTime);
    player.on('seeking', handleSeek);
});
```

Puede acceder a las propiedades por medio del evento

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).